# Vector function algebra

Tags: vectors

Could someone please explain why following is  correct?

$$b+Ch=0$$
$$h=bC^{-1}$$

Note that $b$ is the gradient and $C$ the hessian.

I'm not familiar with algebraic transformations of vector functions. It seems like there are different rules to apply. I would be also glad to know a good resource to learn more about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b$ and $h$ are column vectors, and $C$ is a nonsingular  $(n\times n)$-matrix then $b+Ch=0$ implies $$h=-C^{-1}b\ .$$ If $C$ is the Hessian of some $C^2$-function $f:\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$ at some point $p$ then $C$ is a symmetric matrix. It follows that we also have
$$h'=- b'C^{-1}\ ,$$
whereby $h'$ and $b'$ now are row vectors.

First thing next week should be for you to take in some linear algebra!

Comment: Thank you very much! You're right. I'll start right now!